# YouTube won't take channel art.

Tags: youtube

I upload the channel art, adjust the crop, save it, and then it changes from the upload prompt to a white box. If you refresh the page the upload prompt is back. Tried on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file size is 2MB or less. I had the same problem and this fixed it. They should make sure there is an error that says file is too large so you know.

Comment: Wow. That worked perfectly. Thanks. And wow Google, you know the file size, just reject it instead of failing silently. Thanks!